# Is there a formatting bug with bold fonts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

I noticed a strange thing that seemed like a bug to me.  In this answer that I posted to one of the questions: [Are there some typical mistakes made by native Georgian speakers when speaking Russian?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/80/are-there-some-typical-mistakes-made-my-native-georgian-speakers-when-speaking-r/84#84) I used double-asterisks to make ending of the word bold, e.g. больш**ая** кошка.  In post preview these look just fine, however when I submit it, on the actual post this looks as italicised ending surrounded by single asterisks.  So is this some sort of a bug or did I miss something?

Comment: P.S. please dismiss my edit to the answer in question (hurr), I was testing whether the same bug occurred with underscopes instead of spaces.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for cleaning up.

Comment: You should submit this bug to general meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com, since the engine is the same, this bug can affect other sites as well.

Comment: @lechlukasz good point.  I'll test it in another forum and, if confirmed, will submit to general meta.

Comment: @lechlukasz I tested it in stackoverflow.com - and the behavior is different.  I still get italic font in single asterisks, but the preview shows it correctly, that is, the preview corresponds to the final post.  With stack overflow (and a some other sites), double-asterisk may have special meaning, especially in code blocks.  Either way, the main bug is that the preview doesn't correspond to the final post.

Comment: Still, I think, that http://meta.stackoverflow.com is the place to submit this bug, because there are people who can cope with that problem. AFAIK there's no external bug tracker: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59307/stack-overflow-needs-a-public-bugtracker-meta-stack-overflow-doesnt-cut-it

Comment: On meta.stackoverflow.com there's already a post about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/bug-in-sos-markdown-parsing-for-bold

Comment: @lechlukasz: Sub-metas are fine places for reporting site-wide bugs. If you want to, I'll dig up the meta post (or blog post?) where some SE team member said so.

Comment: Not a bug or no longer reproducible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't support intra-word emphasis. This is by design.

See the blog: [Three Markdown Gotchas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/).

You can use html tags like `<em>` or `<b>` or `<i>` to format in those exceptional cases.

Example:

> больш**ая** кошка

The source for that was:

```
больш<b>ая</b> кошка
```

Comment: The problem is not with Markdown design, as noted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42250/170363), but with inconsistency of preview and the actual post. OP-post says "In post preview these look just fine, however when I submit it, on the actual post this looks as italicised ending". See also this post - http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/890/190 - and then try to edit it and see the preview.